# npm package resolve error even I did exactly what it requires

Tags: angular, npm, ionic-framework, rxjs, node-modules

```
code ERESOLVE
ERESOLVE could not resolve

While resolving: @ionic/angular@7.4.2
Found: rxjs@6.6.7
node_modules/rxjs
  rxjs@"^6.5.3" from the root project
  peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/cdk@16.2.6        
  node_modules/@angular/cdk
    @angular/cdk@"^16.2.6" from the root project
    peer @angular/cdk@"16.2.6" from @angular/material@16.2.6   
    node_modules/@angular/material
      @angular/material@"^16.2.6" from the root project        
  11 more (@angular/common, @angular/core, @angular/forms, ...)

Could not resolve dependency:
peer rxjs@">=7.5.0" from @ionic/angular@7.4.2
node_modules/@ionic/angular
  @ionic/angular@"^7.4.2" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@7.8.1
node_modules/rxjs
  peer rxjs@">=7.5.0" from @ionic/angular@7.4.2
  node_modules/@ionic/angular
    @ionic/angular@"^7.4.2" from the root project
```

it wants rxjs^6.5.3, I did exactly what it want in my package.json. Why it still not happy.

Or it means its ok, just the ionic/angular not ok, so confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what it meant is

```
Found: rxjs@6.6.7
node_modules/rxjs
  rxjs@"^6.5.3" from the root project
```

`@rxjs 6.6.7` is what we had installed. No problem.

But

```
peer rxjs@">=7.5.0" from @ionic/angular@7.4.2
```

So it won't work,

Solved this by downgrading to `@ionic/angular@6.7.5`. It `peers @rxjs^6.5.3` .

`rxjs 6.7.7` is competible.